# How to get the third icon to change in material ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, web-development-server

I was trying to import some icons and for my website but the Material ui documents shows some code which does not allow me to change the existing icon.

> 

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Drawer from '@mui/material/Drawer';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import List from '@mui/material/List';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
// import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider';
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem';
import ListItemButton from '@mui/material/ListItemButton';
import ListItemIcon from '@mui/material/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
import GroupIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Group';
// import InboxIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MoveToInbox';
import MailIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Mail';
import LibraryMusicIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LibraryMusic';

const drawerWidth = 240;

export default function PermanentDrawerLeft() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar
        position="fixed"
        sx={{ width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`, ml: `${drawerWidth}px` }}
      >
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer
        sx={{
          width: drawerWidth,
          flexShrink: 0,
          '& .MuiDrawer-paper': {
            width: drawerWidth,
            boxSizing: 'border-box',
          },
        }}
        variant="permanent"
        anchor="left"
      >
        <Toolbar />
        <Toolbar>
        <Typography variant="h5" noWrap component="div">
            Available Groups
        </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
        <List>
          {['First Room', 'Second Room', 'Third Room'].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem key={text} disablePadding>
              <ListItemButton>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  {index === 2 ? <GroupIcon /> : <LibraryMusicIcon /> : <MailIcon /> }
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={text} />
              </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
        <Toolbar>
        <Typography variant="h5" noWrap component="div">
            Members
        </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </Drawer>
      <Box
        component="main"
        sx={{ flexGrow: 1, bgcolor: 'background.default', p: 3 }}
      >
        <Toolbar />
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

I tried to change the icon for the first element which i was able to do but as soon i try change the icon for the third element the output shows error.

I was expecting that the third icon changes

Comment: `{index === 2 ? <GroupIcon /> : <LibraryMusicIcon /> : <MailIcon /> }` This syntax is incorrect. What is the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

**Upadte**

If there need to be 3 different icons for 3 items, it could be:

```
{index === 0 ? <GroupIcon /> : index === 1 ? <LibraryMusicIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
```

Or it could be:

```
{[<GroupIcon />, <LibraryMusicIcon />, <MailIcon />][index]}
```

Both the above ways should be equivalent.

**Original**

`index` starts from `0`, so the third item will have an `index` of `2`.

If you prefer every third icon change, it could be:

```
{(index + 1) % 3 === 0 ? <LibraryMusicIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
```

But if there is just 3 items to be mapped, it could be as simple as:

```
{index === 2 ? <LibraryMusicIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I have edited the code can you please take look at it. Thankyou.

Comment: @Prab I see, did you mean there need  to be 3 different icons?